# Data modeling in columnar database vs multi-dimensional for reporting

Tags: amazon-redshift, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensions

In my way of learning Redshift (my first columnar database), I am struggling to figure out the approach for designing the model. Columnar database does promote flat table design, yet admits that star schema or snowflake could be a better choice for some cases.

Here is a simple example of where I am struggling

[image]

As you can see multi-dimensional approach have few dimensions and 1 fact table. I could have made it snowflake design but I kept it simple for star schema.

Approach 1: Used common columns from tables (in this scenario demographics). This could reduce the table size for Customer & Store but will include the extra dimension.

Approach 2: Flat table design with all the columns

My Questions:

1. Which approach data modeler use to design data model in columnar databases like Redshift? Or they use different approach?
2. Considering this example, what is the best way to design a data model for data warehousing.
3. Which approach is good for reporting (considering that client PC\Laptop would have limited memory). Or even cloud reporting may become costly when heavy data set is used.
   Approach 3 will produce a massive amount of data set for reporting. This could be a costly affair if doing reporting (using Power BI or Tableau or any other Self reporting tool)
   Multidimenion approach is best for self reporting (cost & performance) but then it defeats the purpose of columnar database.
   Approach 1 is also good for reporting but with more joins & complexity.

Comment: No - multidimensional does not defeat the purpose of columnar reporting. The only time you would every use fully denormalised flat table is when you don't have time to do data modelling. I don't see any reason not to use a star schema.

Comment: Interesting question. I've always viewed a star schema as basically a flat table that reluctantly allowed the performance penalty associated with joins as a way to save disk space. Columnar databases address storage space in other ways, though. So, a big flat table seems like a great approach to me. You should try both and publish the query performance you find. One question, though: Is there a limit to the number of columns you can have in a Redshift table? If so, that might drive your design philosophy.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid But I see people recommending flat table design for columnar database. I also got confused because I don't see reporting benefits but yes I can see great storage savings (which makes sense for database on cloud)

Comment: @Ben Though Redshift says 1,600 column limit and at the same time I heard they say to not make large table for performance benefits (which doesn't make sense to me because columnar database is all about columns so how performance can be degraded). 
Keeping a big table will greatly reduce the cost of storage and processing but I am concerned about the reporting part because then it might need a large dataset to process? (I am not sure how reporting tools fetch data from redshift)

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity I was just thinking about this and, in some ways, the column store is going to work almost like a star schema anyway - as you say, each column is implemented as its own 'table'. FYI, I'm not sure how it affects your situation but I'd avoid select * queries b/c those will force the DB to 'join' all these "column tables' together.

Comment: I’d be interested in any reference about the flat table idea

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid So for row based database, this study clearly says that star schema is better than flat. Which makes sense to me as well (this is what I know when I started data warehousing) 
https://francisjohnpicaso.wordpress.com/2018/12/09/star-schema-vs-flat-table-for-reporting-a-comparative-study/

Comment: @Ben This specific test shows that star schema consume less space than flat, which is opposite to what I have learned so far
https://fivetran.com/blog/obt-star-schema
But in general performance of flat table is better (as per the study)

Comment: Keep in mind that OBT requires much more maintenance overhead

Comment: It seems to me that you are optimising before you have a performance issue.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No no, this is not a project I am working on. I am just learning and this thing can't get off my mind. I don't want to take risk doing test that on Redhsift (due to cost issues). 

I am thinking about the design which could cost less and be fast (because that's what every client wants), it doesn't matter to them if the back end process is complex.

Also, what does OBT means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222349/discussion-between-zerotoinfinity-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Comment: But the back end process also costs money. If you have a complicated process to load data, it costs money

Comment: @Ben this conversation is shifted to the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222349/discussion-between-zerotoinfinity-and-nick-mcdermaid

Comment: You should consider the requirements for how the data will be used. Some BI tools expect / work best with certain table architectures.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, late to the party.

I will post is as answer, because it is too long for a comment.

I saw in chat that test results show that star schema is better. But it was tested on regular (MSSQL), not columnar database (just as vertica, redshift, snowflake, bigquery..).

There is some experience from project implementation where I tested both approaches - OBT and star schema while implementing dwh for reporting. Ths was already more than 2 years ago, so don't expect much details.
Database: Redshift 2 nodes of dc2.8xlarge. Might be a bit overkill, but other option was to have a bunch of lower level nodes, which wouldn't be more cost efficient. This example will be just for one data area.

Data: ~ 6 tables which could be joined as somewhat similar to star schemas. Containing of 3 fact tables and based on denormalization level 5-8 dimensions.

With various approaches and different optimization paths, using star schema it would be common to reach SQL times to about 30 seconds. Which is not bad, but also not too responsive from user perspective.
SQLs on flat denormalized fact tables rarely exceed 5 seconds. Some tables contain more than 100 columns, row counts are between 50M and 100M. To not overcomplicate, we use zstd compression for all columns.
In columnar databases data compresses very well as many similar or same values are used in single column.

We took OBT table approach and there are some pros and cons:

pros:

1. Responsive reports in reporting tool (most important one)
2. Fewer objects for ETL developers to handle.
3. Analysts which query database directly can create simpler queries using less tables.
4. Don't need to worry about data inconsistencies if some dimensions are outdated,  which could happen in star schema.
5. Easier approach for reporting tool cache clearing.
6. Easier reporting performance tuning.
7. Easier modeling in reporting tool, do not need to define table join strategies.

cons:

1. Might take more space. Didn't really tested this closely as storage space is not an issue for us.
2. Filters in reporting tools might take a bit longer to provide list of values (select distinct one_column from table)
3. Table refresh might take a bit longer for one big table compared to multiple smaller tables.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the deep insight about the question. One question though, lets say we have a product sale KPI and business asked us to find out the product which are never sold. Because flat table only will have rows for the product which are sold so there would be no way we can do that analysis unless we have product dimension. 
There could be other situation also. How did you solved those issue?

Comment: I wouldn't call unsold product list as KPI. Your described reporting requirement wouldn't be solved by star schema either. Are you suggesting to have dimension as a driving table and left join fact table? Then you wouldn't be able to use any other dimension. Or cartesian join all dimensions, and then join fact table? Only solution I see is to create custom view in DB or reporting tool side for such purpose. And then client asks to report which product wasn't sold in year 2018, or in some country or any other combination. I see no way to do it efficiently without custom solution for each case.